# setScrollDirection: for CollectionView is not working

Tags: objective-c

I implemented a Collection View programatically in a ViewController and I connected it with the Storyboard but the scrolling is not working and half of the cells do not appear since they are faded to the right:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[FotoCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *myLayout = [[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init]autorelease];
    [myLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myLayout];

}
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the registerClass line in viewDidLoad and set the reuse identifier in the Datasource method for UICollectionViewDelegate as follows -

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  ....

    return cell;
}
```